# .exe из pyinstaller'а не выводит "print()"

Tags: python, pyinstaller, print

Есть программа, подразумевающая вывод нескольких строк текста и запрос на ввод.
В интерпретаторе все работает правильно, но через .exe в консоли - только запрос на ввод.
Вопрос: в чем может быть проблема?
Команда для сборки, насколько помню, была:

```
pyinstaller -F file.py
```

Код для примера:

```
a = [1,2,3]
for i in range(len(a)):
    print (i, ':', a[i])
fldr = input('NAME: ')
```

Ожидание:

```
0:1
1:2
2:3
NAME:
```

Реальность:

```
NAME:
```

python 3.8.10

Comment: Дополните, пожалуйста, вопрос данными о версии Python и командой, которую используете для сборки в .exe

Comment: До упаковки в .exe файл скрипт работает корректно?

Comment: Да. Через командную строку, в SublimeText и PyCharm все так, как нужно

Answer (score 0):

Выяснилось, что Pyinstaller собирал не тот файл (он собирал "промежуточный", который просто не предусматривал вывод принтов). Логика такого поведения пока не ясна. Временное решение - переместить нужный файл в отдельную папку и собирать